# How to load a URL with POST data into GeckoView

Tags: android, http-post, geckoview

How do you load a URL with post data using the "POST" method into GeckoView? On the Android WebView I can do this:

```
view.postUrl(url, postParams.getBytes())
```

I have tried this with GeckoView but it doesn't work:

```
session.load(new Loader().data(postParams.getBytes(), null).uri(url));
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, this is not currently built in to the library. From a GeckoView [chat](https://chat.mozilla.org/#/room/#geckoview:mozilla.org):

> I don't think there's a way to directly load a page passing POST data at the same time. You can download a file that requires POST data using GeckoWebExecutor.fetch https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoWebExecutor.html#fetch-org.mozilla.geckoview.WebRequest- not sure if that's helpful.